# Nautilus fonts went big. 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, nautilus, fonts

After a reboot my nautilus left bar (with bookmars: home, documents, ect..) has big fonts.
I tried to reset nautilus and unity but the font still big.

Tried to remove all .conf dir but nothing.
Also moved my home dir to a backup, and created an empty one. After reboot still big fonts.

If I'll try to access with guest account all fonts are in the correct size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset font size in ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/500536/how-to-reset-font-size-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Already tried this solution, but don't work for me.

Comment: If those helps, http://askubuntu.com/questions/72119/how-do-i-restore-default-settings-and-configuration-but-keep-local-data-instal and http://askubuntu.com/questions/101534/can-i-reset-everything-to-its-factory-default-settings

Comment: I have delete all files and directory from /home/user and rebooted. No change.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same crazy issue but I found that it can be fixed by resetting the fonts to defaults using the Unity Tweak Tool. It's a available in the Software Center. I would like to know why it is doing this, though. I have to reset everything about once a week. :)